# File explorer filtering in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. A task assigned to create drag and drop component. I followed some blogs to do the task, which only accept image file types. Now the task is when clicked on the upload icon it should open file explorer which should only show image type files. I cannot try to figure out how that would work. Part of my codes which i took from various blogs are:

Drag and drop component:

```
import React from "react";
import { useDropzone } from "react-dropzone";
import UploadIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Upload';

const Dropzone = ({ onDrop, accept }) => {
    // Initializing useDropzone hooks with options
    const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({
      onDrop,
      accept
    });
  
    /* 
      useDropzone hooks exposes two functions called getRootProps and getInputProps
      and also exposes isDragActive boolean
    */
  
    return (
      <div className="dropzone-div" {...getRootProps()}>
        <input className="dropzone-input" {...getInputProps()} accept=".gif,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"/>
        <div className="text-center">
           <UploadIcon  fontSize="large"/>
          {isDragActive ? (
            <p  className="dropzone-content"> Release to drop the files here</p>
          ) : (
            <p className="dropzone-content">
             <b> Choose a file </b> or drag it here
            </p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
export default Dropzone;
```

In the app.js

```
import React, { useCallback,useState } from "react";
import './App.css';
import Form from './components/Form';
import DragDrop from './components/DragDrop';
import ImageList from "./components/ImageList";
import cuid from "cuid";

function App() {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState([]);
  const onDrop = useCallback(acceptedFiles => {
   
    // Loop through accepted files
    acceptedFiles.map(file => {
      // Initialize FileReader browser API
      if (!file.name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|PNG|gif|JPEG|png|JPG|gif)$/)) {
        setErrorMessage('please select valid file image');
        //this.setState({ invalidImage: 'Please select valid image.' });
        return false;
      }
      if(file.name.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|PNG|gif|JPEG|png|JPG|gif)$/)){
      const reader = new FileReader();
     
      // onload callback gets called after the reader reads the file data
      reader.onload = function(e) {
        // add the image into the state. Since FileReader reading process is asynchronous, its better to get the latest snapshot state (i.e., prevState) and update it. 
        setImages(prevState => [
          ...prevState,
          { id: cuid(), src: e.target.result }
        ]);
        setErrorMessage();
      };
      // Read the file as Data URL (since we accept only images)
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
      return file;
    });
  }, []);
  return (
    <main className="App">
    <h2 className="App">Drag and Drop Example</h2>
    <br />
    <div className=".dropzone-div">
    <DragDrop onDrop={onDrop} accept={ 'image/*'}/>
    </div>
    <div className="App">
    {errorMessage && <span> {errorMessage} </span>}
    <ImageList images={images} />
   
    </div>
  </main>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `input` element with the `type` as `file`, like so:

```
<span>
  <label for="upload">Upload</label>
  <input id="upload" type="file" accept="image/*" />
</span>
```

You could of course change the `label` to your liking, such as an upload icon.

This is a native HTML element that comes with the functionality you want, out of the box. It is tempting to code everything by hand, especially if you're a beginner. Just remember to search for native solutions before you try a new functionality, or even better, familiarize yourself with the docs of the language/framework you're using.

By the way, here's the MDN doc for the file input element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file